# Pandas raising ValueError when generating Timestamps using for loops

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, datetime, list-comprehension

When generating a few random Timestamps using Pandas Timestamp() method I'm running into this `ValueError: day is out of range for month`. It seems totally illogical and this error is thrown only when using for loops (conventional for loops & list comprehensions). Works fine with while loops. I would like to know why this happens since the logic behind what I'm trying to do is trivial and I don't see any reason for this to happen? I'd appreciate any help regarding this. Here are the code segments:

```
idx = list()
for day in range(10):
    idx.append(pd.Timestamp(year = 1997, month = 1, day = day, hour = 12))

pd.Series(list(ascii_uppercase), index = idx)
```

```
[pd.Timestamp(year = 1997, month = 5, day = i, hour = 14, minute = i + 24, microsecond = i + 49) for i in range(27)]
```

The above two raise ValueError.

```
day = 1
dates = list()

while (day < 31):
    print(pd.Timestamp(year = 2018, month = 6, day = day, hour = 13, minute = 10 + day, second = 26 + day))
    dates.append(pd.Timestamp(year = 2018, month = 6, day = day, hour = 13, minute = 10 + day, second = 26 + day))
    day += 1
```

While the above works fine!.
P.S: The ranges I specified for days did never exceed the total days in the specified month. You can see that yourself in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Oopsies. I figured the issue!

```
range(n)
```

will generate integers starting from 0. Which isn't a valid date! That's why I had that error. That's pretty damn stupid of me. Once I changed

```
range(1, n)
```

It worked fine!